Laravel Web App SMPT not working in GoDaddy hosting
I created a web app using Laravel that sends reminder emails for medication refills to the admin email at xyz@domain.com, which is set up in Google Workspace.
The app is hosted on GoDaddy, but it's not sending emails to xyz@domain.comn email. It works fine from localhost and other servers. I reached out to GoDaddy support, and they recommended using the relay mentioned below.
smtp host=localhost
port=25
smpt auth=false
smtp ssl=false/none 

As per their statement, I have employed the relay shown below.
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=xyz@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="xyz@domain.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"


The mail host of 'localhost' is what is striking me as odd.  I'm not a bit networking guy, but I think that would me GoDaddy has you hosting your web server on the same machine or in the same VM as their mail service, which ... sounds unlikely. They should have an smtp.godaddy.com address or something like that.  You may want to try a free service like MailTrap for testing an SMTP service, or something like SendGrid which I think has a free tier for several thousand free sends a month.

Your mail host is not pointing to an smtp server.
Try referring to this article go get the right settings. Either relay or smtp server.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en
Also, you might need to create an app password for the authentication if you're using an individual gmail account.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhy-you-may-need-an-app-password
